# Accessing music on samba share

Tags: file-system, music

I'm in the process of putting a large amount of music ~1.5TB (in many folders) into a samba share on ubuntu. I'm wondering what a good application to stream this to android would be, currently I can access the samba share with es file explorer, but I don't think it will be good for playing albumbs. Testing it out, it could play individual tracks quite well, but I could find no play all option for a folder in any of its play options. I don't need album art or search by artist, just want to be able to play all songs in a folder quickly/flexibly. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of good samba network music players available on market. For starters you can take a look at [Soumi: Network Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.techsoftpl.musicplayer&hl=en)

Its keys features include..

> - Plays music from shared folders on local SMB/CIFS network, e.g Windows share, WiFi drive, NAS, USB drive attached to router, etc.
> - Plays music from FTP, FTPS, SFTP, and WebDAV servers
> - Browsing and instant searching by artist, album, genre, and title
> - Find, browse and **play music by folder**

*Note; It offers In-app purchases for certain features*

[image]

Other potential candidates include [Kodi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kodi) (which I personally use but is a bit tricky to setup and consumes a bit more battery power) or [BSPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsplayer.bspandroid.free)  which also allow playback of media files  directly via Wi-Fi from your network shared drives/folders.

Another option is using DNLA or UPnP (only downloadside is you need to setup a media server at the other end. In that case you can use DLNA players like Bubble uPnP or Plex.

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threecats.sambaplayer&hl=en&gl=US

aurel f/this so far is the best network player (android)